# Easy way to combine two 2d arrays into a new 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have this code where I store names from 2 different classrooms with their age

```
string[,] Classroom1 = {
                          {"John", "16"},
                          {"Ethan","18"},
                          {"Jake", "17"}
                       }

string[,] Classroom2 = {
                          {"Jeff", "17"},
                          {"Tom","16"},
                          {"Jay", "18"}
                       }
```

How would my 2d array 'MergedClassroom' look like in a function?

Comment: it will be of same type `string[,] `

Comment: Yeah but how do I merge them?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please edit your question to include it.

Comment: I need to do this for a school project and all the answers contain stuff I haven't learned like Enumerables, dictionaries... And the people who ask the questions have complex arrays and I don't know what everything means. I was hoping to get simpler explanations so that's why I ask it with 2 simple arrays. There has to be a much simpler method, right?

Comment: Classroom1.Concat(Classroom2).

Comment: @jdweng Linq methods don't work with 2D arrays.

Comment: Since this is homework I'm guessing you're stuck working with 2D arrays, but if not creating a `Student` class with a `Name` and `Age` (I'm guessing) properties would allow you to use an array or `List` instead making it much easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Below code will help you

```
static void AddToArray(string[,] result, string[,] array, int start = 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); ++j)
        {
            result[i + start, j] = array[i, j];
        }
    }
}

string[,] Classroom1 = {
                {"John", "16"},
                {"Ethan","18"},
                {"Jake", "17"}
            };

string[,] Classroom2 = {
                {"Jeff", "17"},
                {"Tom","16"},
                {"Jay", "18"}
            };

int d1 = Classroom1.GetLength(0) + Classroom2.GetLength(0);
int d2 = Classroom1.GetLength(1) > Classroom2.GetLength(1) ? Classroom1.GetLength(1) : Classroom2.GetLength(1);
string[,] result = new string[d1, d2];

AddToArray(result, Classroom1);
AddToArray(result, Classroom2, Classroom1.GetLength(0));

for (int i = 0; i < result.GetLength(0); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < result.GetLength(1); ++j)
    {
        Console.Write(result[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```